# Pandas moving block of rows

Tags: python, pandas, slice

I would like to select a moving block of 5 rows in a dataframe, but I want to do this starting from the end of my dataframe.  I am having some trouble with the syntax, because of the exclusivity of the slice argument.

For example, the following works for a 1-sized slice, because doing an iloc slice on -1 gives me the final row ...

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    df_live = df_final.iloc[-i]
```

But i'm having trouble scaling this into a multiple row output like the following ...  the following returns nothing:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    df_live = df_final.iloc[-i:-(i+5)]
```

And this other attempt will ignore my last record because the slice excludes record i. Doing an i-1 for the final record doesn't work either (-0 isn't a valid way to refernce the final row).

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    df_live = df_final.iloc[-(i+5):-i]
```

I think this should be very simple, but I haven't had any luck... TYIA

Comment: I guess you may avoid writing your own loops at all and use `pandas` means to get what you want, like `df[::-1].rolling(window=5)`.

Comment: How do I access the contents of a rolling Pandas window ?... I would like to capture the contents of the entire dataframe ... it seems like the examples online use an aggregate function with .rolling for things like averages etc ... I just want to extract the sliced dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I have found a tolerable solution here using df.take()

ultimately I've anchored on using:

```
df_final.take(-(np.arange(5)+1+i)[::-1])
```

This gets me the full contents of the dataframe, based on a 1 through 5 arange, and using the ::-1 to reverse the sort order